# Laptop's battery: can not charge to energy-full-design

Tags: laptop, battery, charging

I have a pretty new laptop. Using it just couple of months. So, battery must be OK. But I am never able to charge it to energy-full-design, even if the battery's indicator in OS shows 100% charge (the win11 and Ubuntu shows 100%). What should I do in order to be able to charge to full level -> to energy-full-design?

This is a battery report:

```
    native-path:          BAT0
    vendor:               HP
    model:                Primary
    serial:               SerialNumber
    updated:              02 Feb 2023 09:41:27 (4 seconds ago)
    has history:          yes
    has statistics:       yes
    battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               discharging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              63,186 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         63,186 Wh
    energy-full-design:  70,07 Wh
    energy-rate:         9,979 W
    voltage:             16,985 V
    charge-cycles:       25
    time to empty:       6,3 hours
    percentage:          100%
    capacity:            90,1755%
    technology:          lithium-ion
    con-name:            &apos;battery-full-symbolic&apos;

 History (charge):
    1675320057  100,000 discharging
    1675320027  0,000   unknown

 History (rate):
    1675320087  9,979   discharging
    1675320057  9,732   discharging
    1675320027  0,000   unknown
```

Comment: As this is a new laptop, it's in warranty and your best bet is contacting HP support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many Lithium-based batteries, including those in Laptops,  Cellphones and electric cars, are never charged to their physical 100% on purpose: For a tiny penalty in capacity (10% or less) you get a huge return in longetivity (factor 3-5).

HP is known to do this and to do this well and the fact, that the battery shows as full in the GUI gives a strong clue, that this is indeed on purpose.

If the laptop in question is indeed designed to not use the extra few %, then the limitation is in the charger firmware - you will not be easily able to circumvent it. My personal opinion is, you shouldn't.